# My ng-view being infinite loop with index.html page angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Good day everybody, i want to ask a little question about angularjs ngview.
I just learned about angular a week ago.

In my code, my web show infinite loop of the index itself, instead if showing the right page. I already search on stackoverflow for the same problem, but still cannot fix my problem.

Here's my app.js code:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{


  $routeProvider.when("/detilsoal/:nomor/:id",
              {
                templateUrl: "/detil_soal.html"
                controller: "soalLengkap"
              }).when("/nilai/:id",
              {
                templateUrl: "/nilai.html",
                controller: "hitungNilai"
              }).otherwise(
              {
                redirectTo: "/"
              });

});
```

Here's my controller (i just want to check if the controller is used correctly):

```
app.controller('hitungNilai', function($scope, $http, $routeParams)
{

  console.log('error');
});
```

And here's my nilai.html view (located in public/nilai.html) :

```
<div class="row" id="head_soal">
    <div id="kotak_dalam" ng-controller="hitungNilai">
            <h2>JUMLAH NILAI</h2>
            <div class="row" id="isi soal" style="padding: 3%;margin-left: 1%;">

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the picture when i go to address:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AaHZ.png)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you are redirectiong to `/` but you didn't initialize

```
.when("/",
         {
         templateUrl: "/detil_soal.html"
         controller: "soalLengkap"
        })
```

use this code...

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{


  $routeProvider.when("/",
              {
                templateUrl: "/detil_soal.html"
                controller: "soalLengkap"
              }).when("/detilsoal/:nomor/:id",
              {
                templateUrl: "/detil_soal.html"
                controller: "soalLengkap"
              }).when("/nilai/:id",
              {
                templateUrl: "/nilai.html",
                controller: "hitungNilai"
              }).otherwise(
              {
                redirectTo: "/"
              });

});
```

Comment: @U R It's still not working. But i am confused because my other url (/detilsoal/:nomor/:id) is working. I also check the network on my broswer and it does load nilai.html.